# Ruby on rails "Could find user with id= create"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

i don't know what's wrong, I tried to add "create" method to my application, and what i get is :

"ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show"
"Couldn't find User with id=create"

And then code

```
# Use callbacks to share a common setup
def set_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

# Permit only specific parameters
```

here's my User controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def create 
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    respond_to do |user|
      if @user.save(user_params)
        user.html { redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User has been created!" }
      else
        user.html { redirect_to create_user_path(@user), :notice => "Sorry, couldn't create user. Try again!" }
      end
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User has been updated!" }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to edit_user_path(@user), :notice => "Sorry, couldn't update user. Try again!" }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |d|
      d.html { redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User has been successfully destroyed :C !" }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share a common setup
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Permit only specific parameters
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
    end
end
```

The thing is, the index page works perfectly fine, but if i try to go somewhere else, like /users/create i get that error.. I tried changing routes, rewriting the code, nothing helps.My routes are like this:

```
# Root '/'
  root "users#index"

  # Show Users
  get "users/:id" => "users#show"
```

Can you guys help me ? I am literally stuck, as to how fix that problem :c

Comment: Try adding @user = User.find(params[:id]) to your show method

Comment: No need for that, he already does that through a before_action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't go to the `create` action via a URL.  It's there to create a new user coming back from the `new.html.erb` file.

If you want to create a new user you could use `/users/new` and add a `new` method to your controller along the lines of:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
end
```

You will also need to change your `routes.rb` file to add all the default actions like:

```
resources :users
```

I suggest you work through http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[This](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) should help you - you're missing `resources :users`, which creates a set of RESTful routes for your controller. This, combined with the other answers should help

Answer (score 0):

In your controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create 
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User has been created!"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update(user_params)
      redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User has been updated!"
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User has been successfully destroyed :C !" }
  end

  private
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
    end
end
```

You are using all RESTful actions, so you can add to `routes.rb`:

```
resources :users
```

And remove this:

```
get "users/:id" => "users#show"
```

Comment: Thanks YOU! ^^ I see what i did wrong, thank you very much ! ^^